Structure of $S$-units of norm $\pm1$ in a real quadratic field
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ be a real quadratic field, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ be an integer, and let $S$ denote the primes of $K$ which divide $n$. Let $\mathcal{O}[1/n]$ be the ring of $S$-integers. I would like to understand its unit group $\mathcal{O}[1/n]^\times$.
We know that $\mathcal{O}^\times\cong\epsilon^\mathbb{Z}\times\mu_2$, where $\epsilon$ is a fundamental unit. Taking valuations gives a map $v : K^\times\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^S$ sending $a\mapsto (v_{p_1}(a),\dotsc,v_{p_r}(a))$, whence an exact sequence
$$1\rightarrow\mathcal{O}^\times\rightarrow\mathcal{O}[1/n]^\times\xrightarrow v\mathbb{Z}^S.$$
Noting that some power of each $p_i$ is principal, one finds that the image of $v$ has full rank, and hence by choosing a splitting, we have
$$\mathcal{O}[1/n]^\times\cong \epsilon^\mathbb{Z}\times\mu_2\times A$$
where $A$ is a free abelian group of rank $|S|$. We have a norm map
$$N : \mathcal{O}[1/n]^\times\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}[1/n]^\times.$$
I'd like to understand the structure of the group of units with norm $\pm 1$. Clearly the units in $\mathcal{O}^\times = \epsilon^\mathbb{Z}\times\mu_2$ all have norm $\pm 1$, so it suffices to understand which units of $A$ have norm $\pm1$. Let $A_{\pm 1}$ denote this subgroup.
If the primes dividing $n$ are all principal, then I believe $A_{\pm 1} = \mathbb{Z}^s$ where $s$ is the number of conjugate pairs of split primes (if $p\mid n$ and $p = \pi\overline{\pi}$, then $\pi/\overline{\pi}\in A_{\pm 1}$). (In particular, $A_{\pm 1} = 0$ if the primes dividing $n$ are all inert.) What does $A_{\pm 1}$ look like if nonprincipal primes are involved? Can we describe a process to find explicit generators for $A_{\pm 1}$?
Relevant references would also be appreciated!

You may apply Hilbert 90 to find S-integers with norm $1$; the quotient is a cohomology group.

Consider the natural exact sequence $1\to\mathcal O^\times\to\mathcal O[\frac 1n]^\times\to\bigoplus_{\mathfrak p|n}\mathfrak p^{\mathbb Z}\to\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ and restrict to norm $\pm 1$ for elements and $1$ for divisors: $$1\to\mathcal O^\times\to\mathcal O\left[\frac 1n\right]^\times_{\pm 1}\to\bigoplus_{ p=\pi\bar\pi|\frac{n}{(n,\mathrm{disc}(K))}}\left(\frac\pi{\bar\pi}\right)^{\mathbb Z}\to\mathrm{Cl}(K).$$
Consequently $$A_{\pm 1}\cong\ker\left(\oplus_{\pi}\left(\frac\pi{\bar\pi}\right)^{\mathbb Z}\to\mathrm{Cl}(K)\right)\cong\ker\left(\oplus_{\pi}\pi^{2\mathbb Z}\to\mathrm{Cl}(K)^2\right)$$, where the sum is over all split $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$ dividing $n$. Thus $A_{\pm 1}$ corresponds to the group of relations satisfied by the classes $[\pi^2]\in\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ for the $\pi$ as above.
